# how can i delete row from posts by user who added this post?

Tags: php, android

this is the code inside android studio i want to delete from posts just with user who add this post from table users by foreign key user_id which references to users whose register

```css
   public class DailogeUbdatePost extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

String HttpUrlDeleteRecord = "http://localhost/DrSiani/DeletePosts.php";

public Context c;
public Dialog d;
public Button deletDialog,ubdateDialoge;
TextView textDialogAdd;
ProgressDialog progressDialog2;
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
String finalResult ;
HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();






public DailogeUbdatePost(Context a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dailoge_ubdate_post);

    deletDialog= (Button) findViewById(R.id.deletDialog);
    ubdateDialoge= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ubdateDialoge);


    deletDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StudentDelete(finalResult);

        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.BackBtnDialogDR:

            dismiss();

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}
public void StudentDelete(final String uerId) {

    class DeletePosts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog2 = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Loading Data", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            progressDialog2.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          
            hashMap.put("user_id", params[0]);

            finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpUrlDeleteRecord);

            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    DeletePosts deletePosts = new DeletePosts();

    deletePosts.execute(uerId);
}

}
```

this is the code of deleting i have tow table 1_user_info(has users who signed in) 2_posts that user will post it table posts has user_id foreign key 
i want  to delete post with user who add this post just i wish to help me pleas

```css
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'connecttomysql.php';

 $con = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

 $ID = $_POST['user_id'];

$Sql_Query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$ID'";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
 echo 'Record Deleted Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: And which part is not working?...did you test your server endpoint `http://devsinai.com/DrSiani/DeletePosts.php` with another tool, like `postman`

Answer (score 1):

try this solution :)
you can edit the posts table and add new row contain id for every post
and the query will be

`$Sql_Query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$ID' and post_id='$posts_ID'";`

now you can delete only the wanted post.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you format the code/query parts of your answer to make it more readable?  See the "help" link at the top right of the answer window.

Comment: i don't understand how you want to connect with other table?!

Comment: @IbrahimHusin There is no such thing as "connecting" to tables. I think you would need to complete and SQL Tutorial before completing this project. Try this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/